# I need help Identifying where exactly this set came from

Tags: chess-set, identify-this

[image]

I need help Identifying this.
My grandfather was in ww2 and at one point in the navy he went to Russia and met a Russian Naval Officer to whom he traded for this set, and the officer said he got it from his grandfather, but I'd like some true speculation on it please.

Comment: Can you precise the size of these chessmen ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the same set on ebay. More pictures of yours would be helpful.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vtg-Ceramic-Duncan-Medieval-Style-32Pc-Chess-Set-Hand-Painted-Faces-Detailed-74/263416351119?hash=item3d54d6898f:g:GaoAAOSw4A5Y0WX2

Perhaps the seller can help you learn more.

If you Google for "ceramic duncan medieval chess", you'll get a lot of hits.

Answer (score 1):

Other than colors, that looks identical to a set my mother made for me back in the 1970's or early 80's at a local ceramic studio. She made it from molded greenware (unfired clay) and hand painted it. She made a few of these for other chess playing family members & friends, using different color combinations.

While the story you state is nice, I'm sorry to say it seems likely to me that the set in your picture was made in a similar fashion to mine, instead of being acquired in a trade from an officer in the Russian Navy.

Update: A similar set is now on display at the World Chess Hall of Fame. The first molds for sets like this were probably created in 1960's or 1970's by a company then known as Duncan Ceramics Products. As long as the link is good, you can see the set on display and read  more at:
https://worldchesshof.org/exhibit/featured-chess-sets-2022

[image: Image of chess set]